# cURL to traverse a login with many pages

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am trying to use cURL to automate a login with multiple steps involved.  The problem I am running into is that I get the first page of the login fine but the next page I hit I must select or hit a link to continue.  How the heck do I "keep going".  I've tried taking the next URL and putting it into my cURL code but it does not work as it just goes directly to that page and errors because I have not gone to the first page of the login process.  Here is my code.

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 $data = array('fp_software' => '', 'fp_screen' => '', 'fp_browser' => '','txtUsername' => "$username", 'btnLogin' => 'Log In');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;  rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/Login.aspx'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close ($ch);
```

The next url is www.website.com/PassMarkFrame.aspx - Basically I need to crawl threw this login process.

I tried this...but it didn't work.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/Login.aspx'); // use the URL that shows up in your <form action="...url..."> tag
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/PassMarkFrame.aspx'); // use the URL that shows up in your <form action="...url..."> tag
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Is that the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't close the curl handle after each stage. if cookies are being set, and you haven't configured the cookiejar/cookiefile options, then you start with a brand new sparkly fresh and clean CURL with no "memory" of the previous requests.

Keep the same curl handle going, and any cookies set by the site will be preserved.

Comment: Made the change above but still having the same result.  Do I have to allow it to store cookies?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked for me after setting cookies and getting rid of the curl_close.